# What happens when you revive someone in TDM?

Tags: battlefield-3

When you revive someone in TDM, and they get killed again, will this count as another kill for the opposite team?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TDM and SQDM, when you revive someone, kill gets reverted. Kill counter of the team/squad which killed him goes down. If they kill him again, counter goes up to the same number as before revive.

Comment: Thanks, this makes the medic not completely useless in deathmatch :)

Comment: Does only the ticket get reverted, or the kills invidiual gets as well?

Comment: @Bora player stats never go down, except for like accuracy.

Comment: @Bora I've never played TDM or SQDM, but in CQ your death-counter gets increased only after 5 seconds of revive-time. However, when you are killed in the vehicle or you are out of the combat zone, the counter is increased immediately.

Comment: Battlefield runs on a 'ticket' count, not a 'kill' count. When you are killed, your team loses a ticket. When you are revived, your team is 'refunded' the ticket. The other person still gets credit for the kill.

Comment: @MyFaJoArCo This is because when you are shot, you take a lesser amount of damage (bullets) and presumably can be revived. You have a certain time period before you bleed out and are unrevivable. When you are in a vehicle and the vehicle is destroyed you take so much damage (since you were involved in an explosion), that you cannot be revived so there is no bleed out and the ticket is lost immediately. I don't know what you mean by out of the combat zone. If you mean outside the map boundaries, then this is just to prevent people from staying outside the map with a medic and killing people.

Comment: @SSumner It's actually combat area (but "zone" is the closest synonym). And why did you write all this? I wasn't asking :)

Comment: @SSumner: not quite accurate, as **deathmatch modes** do run on kill count, not ticket count. As for revive mechanics, also doesn't seem correct, as by that logic if someone gets headshot from tank cannon, should be unrevivable, while actually you can revive them.

Comment: @SSumner Actually, the ticket is lost when you respawn. Since a revive means you won't have to respawn, then your team won't lose the ticket. Your body becomes "unrevivable" as soon as you actually respaw, and you can only be revived if you leave a body, which does not happen if you were in a vehicule.